# Changes to old questions’ approach?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

With thousandsand thousands of questions and answers, UX.SE became a huge site with lots of useful content. However, due to the nature of our discipline, many answers are really outdated, when not completely wrong by current standards. Yet, good current questions are closed because a 5 years old answer exists, or old questions with no accepted answer are bumped to home page. As an example, right now I can see a [question from 2010 with no accepted answer asking for speed for website’s load](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5529/how-long-should-a-page-take-to-load). Of course, any answer provided will be completely irrelevant nowadays. I understand this was modeled under stackoverflow premises, but coding practices rarely change (there might be some changes related to new tools or languages or libraries, but the logic remains intact), while UX evolves on a day by day basis.

So I’d like to propose this:

1. Questions with no accepted answer and more than 1 year old can’t be bumped
2. Questions can’t be deeemed as duplicated if the previous question is older than X years (for example, 2 years). System should recognize it automatically when a reviewer marks a duplicate.
3. Questions older than 1 year should be closed to new answers.
4. Questions with no answers and no votes for 3 months should be closed automatically (with previous notice to creator so s/he can modify it)
5. Answers more than 3 years old shouldn’t  be considered as correct for new questions. We could still use the “possible duplicate “ reason, but this time the system should say something like

> there’s a possible answer for your question but it is from {date}.
>   Please consider this answer first”

Just throwing some ideas, of course they’d need some discussion and adjustments

Comment: From seeing a few "duplicate" questions being raised recently, I would agree with this.